# Is there anyway to order in which multiple dispatcher servlet pick a request?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

We had a monolithic application where there was a dispatcher servlet handling all the requests. Later we adopted web-fragment to have more modularity in app. But with this approach we are having multiple dispatcher servlet. one for each web-fragment. So now we have `wf1-servlet(/wf1/*), wf2servlet(/wf1/*)` and main-servlet in `web.xml(/*)` [we can't avoid this as there are lot of urls out there which can't be namespaced].

Is there anyway to order the execution of the servlet so that main-servlet get picked in the last as this works on `/*`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<url-pattern>` tag to map a specific url to specific servlets:

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>wf1servlet</servlet-name>  //servlet name
 <servlet-class>package.Wf1servlet</servlet-class>  //servlet class
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>wf1servlet</servlet-name>   //servlet name
 <url-pattern>/wf1/*</url-pattern>  //how it should appear
</servlet-mapping>
```

you can **also** inside the the servlet you can **forward** a request to another specific request like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://otherserver:otherport/url");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

//set http method if required
connection.setReqeustMethod("POST");

//set request header if required
connection.setRequestProperty("header1", "value1");

//check status code
if(connection.getResponseCode() == 200){

InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
//transfer is to the required output stream
} else {
 //write error
}
```

also I think the mapping order of servlets are their came order in the **web.xml** file, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872973/what-happens-if-i-have-two-servlet-mappings-in-web-xml-that-match-a-request) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202249/java-servlet-url-mapping) you can see something useful about it

Comment: Thanks! Yes mapping order is same as it appears in web.xml. Reordering the definition in web.xml worked.

Comment: @Raj, great, happy to see that your problem has solved!