# How to map servlet java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-mapping

currently reading Head First Servlet Jsp. I currently stuck in mapping servlet. This is probably a stupid question but how can I map a servlet url pattern properly? I am using eclipse mars and this is my first time with jsp/servlets. I always check the generate web xml when creating a dynamic web project

This is what in the default web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>HeadFirst</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

It runs using this

```
http://localhost:8080/HeadFirst/Ch2Servlet
```

but when I add this just below the display name

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Ch2Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.test.hello</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Ch2Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

it gives me a 404 error and this is the url

```
http://localhost:8080/HeadFirst/servlet/com.test.hello.Ch2Servlet
```

Here's my servlet class

```
@WebServlet("/Ch2Servlet")
public class Ch2Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
        out.println("<h1>Hello World</h1>" + "<br>");
        out.println("Date today is " + today + "<br>");
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }
}
```

btw i have read this  but still am confused
[Java Servlet URL Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202249/java-servlet-url-mapping)
[Servlet Mapping using web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198312/servlet-mapping-using-web-xml)
edit added my serlvet class

Comment: I see you're already using annotations, to change the URL just change the value of `@WebServlet("/Ch2Servlet")`.

Comment: I tried changing the annotation and this url now works
@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")
http://localhost:8080/HeadFirst/HelloWorld
so do annotation makes url pattern useless or obsolete

Comment: You need to restart the server after you change the mapping. Yes the annotation replaces the `web.xml` approach of changing the mapping.

Comment: So if its servlet version 3 up it recommended to just use annotation instead of mapping? By the way when i remove the annotation i get an error instatiating servlet class

Comment: Yes, is easier to set the path using annotation, the error that you get is probably because you have set the wrong `<servlet-class>` or `<servlet-name>` in the `web.xml` file.

Answer (score 3):

The url is not:

```
http://localhost:8080/HeadFirst/servlet/com.test.hello.Ch2Servlet
```

It will be:

```
http://localhost:8080/HeadFirst/HelloWorld
```

More specifically, it will be the value that you set as `<url-pattern>...</url-pattern>`

Comment: I cannot see `/servlet` in the URL pattern for the servlet.

Comment: That is generated by eclipse when i click run as application

Comment: @Onedaynerd don't blindly trust autogenerated resources, even less when you're in learning phase.

Comment: @Onedaynerd If you are using `Servlet 3.0` you should take a look at annotations.

Comment: still getting a 404 error, let me edit and post my code as well